# Sed command does not replace string with special characters

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a script which is getting value from a ".properties" file. It replaces the value successfully if it is a simple string but if contains escape characters like ('\') it does not work. Can anybody point out please that what to do, i have searched on the internet but unable to understand the "REGEX".

**Script File:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Omer's First Script
#Include Properties File
. directoryPaths.properties
echo "Start"

sed -i "s/DONEDIRECTORY/$DoneDirectory/" *TestFile*



echo "finish"
```

**directoryPaths.properties**

```
DoneDirectory=/home/omerkhalid/Documents/Test/Done
```

**TestFile.txt**

This is a test Document.

DONEDIRECTORY

**Error:**

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'
```

**Note:**
If i change the value of "DoneDirectory" to simple string i.e. "Done" , it works fine. But with "/" escape characters it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

**Problem** is not with the sed command but with the contents of the variable `$DoneDirectory`.

In the sed command

```
sed -i "s/DONEDIRECTORY/$DoneDirectory/" *TestFile*
```

`/` is used as the delimitter, there by `sed` expects only 3 slashes following the `s` command. But once the variable `$DoneDirectory` is substituted there are 8 `/` which gives the error

**Solution**

Use some other delimeters in `sed` like

```
sed -i "s#DONEDIRECTORY#$DoneDirectory#" *TestFile*
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the variable `$DoneDirectory` contains sed's default command delimiter `/` I would use a different delimiter:

```
sed -i "s#DONEDIRECTORY#$DoneDirectory#" *TestFile*
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that sed is not the right tool for this job. Sure, you can work with other delimiters, but if the other delimiter shows up in your string (or a backslash, or something else that sed interprets), it's still going to explode. I believe awk is better suited:

```
awk -v subst="$DoneDirectory" '{ sub("DONEDIRECTORY", subst); print $0 }' TestFile
```

Note: use `gsub` instead of `sub` if `DONEDIRECTORY` can show up more than once in a line and both should then be substituted.